# ProgressBar not loading

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm making a small game for school and I want to use a ProgressBar as an XP(Experience) bar.

```
private static final int PROGRESS = 0x1;
private ProgressBar mProgress;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private int mProgressStatus;

mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.xpBar);

new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int xp = Integer.parseInt(textViewXPValue.getText().toString());
            int XPNEXT = Integer.parseInt(textViewXpNextLevel.getText().toString());
            while (mProgressStatus < XPNEXT) {
                mProgressStatus = xp;

                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                    }
                }, 10);   
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

The variable:

```
Integer.parseInt(textViewXpNextLevel.getText().toString());
```

is equal to the maximum xp needed to level up. And

```
Integer.parseInt(textViewXPValue.getText().toString());
```

is equal to the current xp the player has.

The progress bar shows up and no error occurs. It just wont display the progress.

Any ideas?

Comment: use postDelayed instead of post to update ProgressStatus

Comment: post your code with postDelayed what u have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a semi-colon at the end of while (....) line.
It is not letting your while block to execute.
Get rid of it and it will work.

EDIT:

You have not set max value:

```
mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
                mProgress.setMax(100);
```

This will make your progress bar work fine.

Comment: Ok that made something happen. Now the progress bar just shows that it's full. Even though the status is less than the max

Answer (score 0):

hey there is a semi colon  at the end of while.... remove it n then try....

while (mProgressStatus < XPNEXT);

it should be  while (mProgressStatus < XPNEXT)